# Check if user exists on Firebase when text field changes

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to change my login button to a register button automatically. If a user do exist on the database, the button is login, if it doesn't, the button changes. So far my code looks like this but it doesn't work.

```
    func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    if emailCell.textField.text != "" && passwordCell.textField.text != "" {

        let email = emailCell.textField.text
        let usersRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")

        usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue("\(email)").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {
                self.forwardButton.setTitle(buttonTitle.new.rawValue, forState: .Normal)
            } else {
                self.forwardButton.setTitle(buttonTitle.login.rawValue, forState: .Normal)
            }
        })
        self.forwardButton.hidden = false

    } else { forwardButton.hidden = true }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you set the delegate?

Comment: The text change observer works, I wrote some code inside this function to write to Firebase and it worked, what doesn't work is the query.

Comment: So it was the delegate?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: The query to Firebase doesn't do anything. The button title doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The query doesn't work because I'm trying to access the database before I authenticate the user.

I can make the users node public, but that would be risky. Instead, what I did was to enable anonymous auth and sign in anonymously just to make the query and sign out right after executing the query.

Hope that helps.